# Can an infinite dimensional vector space contain no linearly independent lists?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Is it possible for a vector space $V$, where $\dim V =\infty$, to contain no linearly independent list of vectors?

That is, in a proof concerning infinite dimensional vector spaces, is it "legal" to assume that an arbitrary list of vectors in the space is independent, without having to show it?

Comment: you can consider polynomial space with coefficients from $\mathbb R$ with ordinary scalar multiplication and ordinary polynomial addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out. Now that I think about it, it's a pretty trivial answer, but I wanted to leave this here in case someone else was ever curious like I was.

Since you can take any $v_1\in V$, $v\neq0$, this single vector list $v_1$ is linearly independent.

What's more interesting, is that since it's an infinitely dimensional space, there's another vector, $v_2 \not \in span(v_1)$, so the new list $v_1, v_2$ is linearly independent. Repeating this means that we can continue appending new vectors $v_n$ *forever*, so I think that the answer to the original question is: "quite the opposite".